# How to get the maximum global work size with OpenCL C++ bindings?

Tags: c++, opencl

I want to get the maximum global work size. 
I don't want  a kernel OpenCL will try to choose the best one for you, which MAY or MAY NOT be the maximum size.

To do this I want to specify the size when call `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`.
e.g:

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global_size, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

[clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo.html), indicates :

*CL_KERNEL_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE : This provides a mechanism for the application to query the maximum global size that can be used to execute a kernel (i.e. global_work_size argument to clEnqueueNDRangeKernel) on a custom device given by device or a built-in kernel on an OpenCL device given by device.*

How can I get `CL_KERNEL_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE` with OpenCL C++ bindings ?

I do this

```
cl::array<size_t, 3> kernel_global_work_size = my_kernel.getWorkGroupInfo<CL_KERNEL_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE>(my_device);
```

But I got error :

```
cl2.hpp:5771:12: note: candidate: template<class T> cl_int cl::Kernel::getWorkGroupInfo(const cl::Device&, cl_kernel_work_group_info, T*) const
     cl_int getWorkGroupInfo(
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cl2.hpp:5771:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
cl2.hpp:5782:9: note: candidate: template<int name> typename cl::detail::param_traits<cl::detail::cl_kernel_work_group_info, name>::param_type cl::Kernel::getWorkGroupInfo(const cl::Device&, cl_int*) const
         getWorkGroupInfo(const Device& device, cl_int* err = NULL) const
```

And with this code

```
cl::array<size_t, 3> kernel_global_work_size;
my_kernel.getWorkGroupInfo<cl::array<size_t, 3>>(my_device, CL_KERNEL_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE, &kernel_global_work_size);
```

I got OpenCL error -30 (Invalid Value)

`my_kernel` is not Built-in Kernel 
e.g: `cl::Kernel my_kernel = cl::Kernel(program, "my_kernel");`
`my_device` is not Custom device.
e.g: `cl::Device device = myDevices[0];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as your call matches the signature:

https://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/classcl_1_1_kernel.html

```cpp
template <cl_int name> typename
detail::param_traits<detail::cl_kernel_work_group_info, name>::param_type getWorkGroupInfo(const Device& device, cl_int* err = NULL) const;
```

It looks like the `param_traits` which is generated via Macros is not declared for `CL_KERNEL_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE`. That would be a bug in the headers. ([GitHub issue created by OP](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-CLHPP/issues/43))

For some entries 
[here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo.html) 
there are missing entries
[here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-CLHPP/blob/master/input_cl2.hpp#L1218)
.

Alternatively, you can use the version returning an error code, and the info via an output parameter, that should work around the issue:

```cpp
template<typename T>
cl_int getWorkGroupInfo(const Device &device, cl_kernel_work_group_info name, T *param) const;
```

Call could look like:

```cpp
cl::array<size_t, 3> result;
kernel.getWorkGroupInfo<decltype(result)>(device, CL_KERNEL_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE, result);
```

My question to you would be: *Did you try it yourself? Did the result not match your expectations?*

---

**Did you get an CL_INVALID_VALUE?**

> [...] on a custom device given by device or a built-in kernel on an OpenCL device given by device.
>
> **If device is not a custom device or kernel is not a built-in kernel**, clGetKernelArgInfo returns the error CL_INVALID_VALUE.

See [OpenCL 1.2 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf), pages 14 and 15:

> **Built-in Kernel:** A built-in kernel is a kernel that is executed on an OpenCL device or custom
>   device by fixed-function hardware or in firmware. Applications can query the built-in kernels
>   supported by a device or custom device. A program object can only contain kernels written in
>   OpenCL C or built-in kernels but not both. See also Kernel and Program.
>
> **Custom Device:** An OpenCL device that fully implements the OpenCL Runtime but does not
>   support programs written in OpenCL C. A custom device may be specialized non-
>   programmable hardware that is very power efficient and performant for directed tasks or
>   hardware with limited programmable capabilities such as specialized DSPs. Custom devices are
>   not OpenCL conformant. Custom devices may support an online compiler. Programs for
>   custom devices can be created using the OpenCL runtime APIs that allow OpenCL programs to
>   be created from source (if an online compiler is supported) and/or binary, or from built-in kernels
>   supported by the device. See also Device.

**For regular kernels and devices**, the standard constrains the work group size (device property), while the **global size is only constrained by the range of the used `size_t`**. See [clEnqueueNDRangeKernel](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html).

Comment: Yes I try like this 
`cl::array<size_t, 3> kernel_global_work_size = my_kernel.getWorkGroupInfo<CL_KERNEL_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE>(my_device);`
but I got error.
What does `cl_kernel_work_group_info name`& `T * param`means?

Comment: Please post the error then, and verify whether you are using a built-in kernel, or a custom device, as the call will return `CL_INVALID_VALUE` else.

Comment: Updated the answer with an example call for the alternative syntax, maybe that works. For further analysis please post a simple reproducer.

Comment: as you say in "How to get CL_KERNEL_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE values? #43" (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-CLHPP/issues/43#issuecomment-384699924) This seems to be a bug in cl.hpp and cl2.hpp.

Comment: As was pointed out, you can only use this for custom or built-in kernels. For regular kernels it is not a valid call (and returns CL_INVALID_VALUE ). Are you sure you aren't thinking maximum local work group size (not global)?